# Ruby on Rails Secrets.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just want to make sure I'm not misinterpreting this but if I am using environment variables in my config/secrets.yml file should I still be concerned about pushing it to a public repo?  I see many posts about adding this file to git-ignore to protect credentials but if they're passed in as environment variables it shouldn't be a problem correct?

Comment: What is one of those posts? This definitely shouldn't be in gitignore file, but I am just curious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are passed as environment variables, there's no problem at all, because the only thing you can see in fIle contents is that variable name, and it's not a secret. So it can be pushed to your repo without any fears.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you put your secrets in gitignore and make sure they are variables, it will be ok! You should definitely check out Figaro, as it handles that for you

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, you can safely push `secrets.yml` if it doesn't actually hold the values.

*When* I use ENV (or [Figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro)), I usually just eliminate the `secrets.yml` file, and move the ENV assignments into their relevant config or initializer file. To me, that is more clear and modular than having a secrets file in the repo.

However, one could also argue that keeping them in secrets.yml is just as clear, because that's where Rails devs know to look, and they'll immediately see they need to set them in ENV.

Just some food for thought.

Comment: Yes, and when some other programmer comes to continue working on your app, he will curse you for having to define and track changes all over the application instead of having it all in one place! Also, you will have have different initializes for development, test and production environment. A catastrophe waiting to happen.

Comment: They won't have to track changes everywhere, because the relevant assignments (meaning where the ENV value is assigned to its relevant variable inside Rails) will be grouped with their relative concern/gem/etc. And you won't have different initializers, because that's the entire point of ENV.

Comment: In other words, @Aleks just demonstrated that there is more than one school of thought around ENV, secrets.yml, etc. The various approaches, and their reasoning, are well illustrated in the last few sections of the Figaro readme.

Comment: When you are mentioning Figaro, it means that you will introduce a new gem just for the secrets. Even-though it might be a good option, but there a number of gems that can be added which are not that necessary, and if you start polluting Gemfile in such early stage like setting environment, then you  can start having a lots of gems quite soon, that is why I would use just a simple `secrets` rather then use a new gem just to replace similar functionality. At least that is my two cents :)

Comment: I don't disagree with you on that, @Aleks, but I feel that is getting off track of the question. The OP did not ask when or why to use ENV, or an ENV gem. Moreover, nowhere in my answer did I recommend that you use Figaro just to handle secrets (personally, I only use it to manage Heroku ENV's). I simply explained the config pattern I tend to use in the case (or similar cases, like using Figaro) that the OP described.